# Show that if $K \leq H \leq G$ and $K \triangleleft G$ then $K \triangleleft H$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Show that if $K \leq H \leq G$ and $K \triangleleft G$ then $K \triangleleft H$

My try:

Let $a\in H$ then $a\in G $ because $H\leq G$

And how $K \triangleleft G$ then $aKa^{-1} \leq K \ \ \ \forall  \ a \in H$ (because $a$ is in $G$ too) then $K \triangleleft H$ is right?

Comment: Your reasoning is fine.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine.

---

It even works for equality, so you can say, if $K\le H\le G$ and $K\unlhd G$, then

$$K\unlhd H.$$